# How to make 301 redirect in Node JS project with Express JS router?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have [Topic Search](http://devox.io) and Google and all search engines want to have 301 redirect, my project is set up on [Heroku Cloud](https://www.heroku.com/) use node server and have problem whit redirect 301 'domain.com' to 'www.domain.com'....

Comment: What did you try so far to make it work? 
where exactly is the problem? 
How did you try to set up a 301?
Are you sure the problem can't be solved via settings in heroku?

Comment: What is the problem with the example shown in the express docs, the one shown when you search for `express 301 redirect`  in google on the first place?

Comment: I try to redirect whit index.php file to access .htaccess but I set up node server. Now work on "res.redirect(301, 'http://example.com');" is Express JS example but for now is not work....

Comment: Yes I found "express 301 redirect - res.redirect(301, 'example.com');"" this but how to setup when i put this on server.js and run it  have error - "Reference Error: res is not defined" how to defined res ???

Comment: I don't know, I read a lot of documentation about "heroku" they offer a solution "Amazon S3" I don't know what to do if you have similar problem please give me some hint...

Comment: You don't define `res` this provided by express.js as argument in the callback of a route (the fundamental basic of express.js). `[...]I try to redirect whit index.php file to access .htaccess but I set up node server.[...]` that absolutely does not make any sens. You should step by step understand the different techniques. First learn _node.js_ , then _express.js_  and then try to set this up on a webspace.

Comment: ОК, thank you t.niese for comment but the next time write Something constructive ...!

Comment: until I came to this function "
app.get('/', function(request, response, next) {
    if(request.headers.host=="http://example.com") {
        response.redirect(301, 'http://www.example.com');
    }
    else{
        next();
    }
})" but it works only on the local server on my real server not

Answer (score 0):

So I found the problem and fixed, all is coming of **request.headers.host** in my case is only **domain.com** and the function is:

```
app.get('/', function(request, response, next) {
if(request.headers.host =="domain.com") {
    response.writeHead(301, {'Location':'http://www.domain.com'+ request.url, 'Expires': (new Date).toGMTString()});
    response.end();
}
else{
    next();
}})
```